# firebase.storage() giving Uncaught Type Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, typeerror

I am using Firebase with web app, and trying to create a downloadable link for a image stored in my firebase storage.

I get a Uncaught Type Error in the line:

```
firebase.storage()
```

Here's the error:
Error Code
[image]

I have Added the Firebase Configuration and the Storage SDK

This is my JS code:

```
var storage = firebase.storage()      // I am getting an error in this line
ref_to_image = storage.ref('ZT.png');
storage.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    console.log(url)
})
```

I import firebase like this:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.10/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you have something like instanceIdentifier in your code? or is it from firebase?

Comment: it's from firebase

Comment: can you show how you import firebase in your project? did you use this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start ?

Comment: Okay but did you make this configuration part - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#add-bucket-url ?

Comment: Yeah, I did it.

Comment: Please edit your HTML to import the same version of all Firebase SDKs.